# android rounded button number pad with weights

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to make dynamic number pad view with rounded shape but the problem is this when i assign background it not showing properly i am using weights so it works on all screen sizes and orientation how can i achieve this is my layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pin_code_first_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pin_code_second_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pin_code_first_row"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pin_code_third_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pin_code_second_row"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pin_code_fourth_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pin_code_third_row"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my rounded shape

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <!-- fill color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- radius -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- corners -->
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image: mylayout]

but i want to make my layout look like this

[image]

how can i make this layout without using static spacing and sizes with weights please help me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: don't use weight, try to give equal height and weight to each view.

Comment: post here your @drawable/rounded code

Comment: @GovindaPaliwal check my edited question please

Answer (score 4):

Use ConstraintLayout as below:

Here is your code: 
**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#75A5CB"
    android:padding="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnterCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter Access Code"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEnterCode"
        tools:text="..." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCode" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="4"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="5"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="6"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="7"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="8"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="9"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_0"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Shape Drawable: 
**your_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#4588C0" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

If you want to display pressed/selected button with white color then you have to create selector drawable and give it in background of button.

[image: Layout Screenshot]

**Edit: If you don't want to give static vertical margin, use below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#75A5CB"
    android:padding="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnterCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter Access Code"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEnterCode"
        tools:text="..." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCode" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="4"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="5"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="6"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="7"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="8"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="9"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pin_code_button_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_0"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_blue"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDelete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pin_code_button_0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's good exmple with constraint layout. can you please explain how  `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"`   works.

Comment: `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` is used to move the view to left and right side from the constraint position. `0.5` means view will remain in the center. You can read more regarding it [here ](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1). Just search `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` in this page.

Comment: @VirajPatel how can i set vertical bias? if i don't want to give vertical spacing static

Comment: @MateenChaudhry I edited my answer in the case of if you don't want to give static vertical spacing. It can be done without vertical bias.

Answer (score 2):

Change Your background drawable with this

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<!-- fill color -->
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

<!-- radius -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

<size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"/>
<!-- corners -->
<corners
    android:radius="2dp"/>
```

Change size as per your need,
You can use constraint layout or something else to achieve this kind of design

for u @Mateen Chaudhry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_30">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:text="3"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:text="4"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:text="5"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:text="6"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:text="7"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/four"/>
```

one alternative solution is use textview instead of buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_30">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="3"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="4"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="5"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="6"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_corners"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="7"
    android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/four"/>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you please give me an example of constraint layout please?

Comment: can I comment this?!

Comment: @MateenChaudhry, I have updated my answer, because for comment i would be to long

Comment: the rounded buttons are not showing circle exactly its showing in rectangle

Comment: for that u need to make a background drawable as I have posted above,
Or else change buttons to textviews

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176533/discussion-between-akash-dubey-and-mateen-chaudhry).

Answer (score 2):

First i will tell you to use Contraint Layout that is latest one and more efficient in designing. @Viraj Patel answer he did with constraint layout.

But you want to acheive same design in relative layout. It quite be easy. Have a look at this

**Step 1**
Create center button first to make it center vertically & horizontally. All you need is add this line to your center button.

> android:layout_centerInParent="true"

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am added static width & height to make it background circle. If you want to make circle of button using `WRAP_CONTENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` you done at runtime in java code. Here am using static value.

Above xml code will give you like this
[image]

**Step 2**
Then you can add more buttons depending on the center buttons and this two more property values.

> android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>   android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Now i add `Digit4` & `Digit6` which is vertically aligned to `Digit5`. Below code will give you the results

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add `to_leftof` & `to_rightof` property and vertically align property to this buttons & add margins value as well.

Above code will give you
[image]

**Step 3**
Now i add `Digit2` & `Digit8` which is horizontally aligned to `Digit5`. Below code will give you the results

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add `layout_below` & `layout_above` property and horizontal align property to this buttons & add margins value as well.

Above code will give you
[image]

**Step 4**
Add corner digits with help of relative layout property `to_leftof` `to_right_of` `layout_above` `layout_below`. Have a look at this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_digit8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And your output is
[image]

**Step 4**
Finally add zero as well.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_digit8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit0"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FINAL OUTPUT**

[image]

**Added**
This will centering your layout on all device size & also centering on landscape mode.

**shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="30dp"/>
<stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="2dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

**UPDATED**

You need to use `ConstraintLayout`. Have a look at this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit0_Left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_digit6"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_digit0_right"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit0_right"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit0_Left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit0_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_digit0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_digit0_Left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_digit0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_digit7" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />
```

**OUTPUT on 5" inch display**
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your detail answer but the main problem is this margins in small  screen devices this margin are too big is there any way to assign these margins according to screen sizes

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. If you want to adapt different screen sizes you need to create layout in seperate folder. Have a look at this [Responsive Android UI Design](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes). We can use contraint layout for adaptation on diffrent screen sizes  but in order achieve circle buttons in layout we need to do dynamically. So far i created in XML have a look at this it adapt sizes on diffrent screens. In this layout all values matched to constraint no static values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could work with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="4"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="5"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="6"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="7"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="8"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="9"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

And if you using **"dp"** for margin and padding, you shouldn't have any problems with different devices and screen sizes.

Comment: @K. Dexter can i also give spacing with weights in this layout?

Comment: You could add `View` s between the button without any background and work with weights.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use table layout when you want to create such layout. In table layout handling weight is so easy. Another point is you have to put weight on button container layout. Not for button itself.

```
<TableRow android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_half">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="1"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="2"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="3"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_half">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="4"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="5"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="6"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_half">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_7"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="7"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_8"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="8"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_button_9"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            android:text="9"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</TableRow>
```

And this is final view and you can change distances and margin and get your desired layout:
[image]

Hope helpful!