# Set textview below another textview in horizontal linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How to set TextView object **tvOperationDesc** below **tvOperationName**

This is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOperationName"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOperationDesc"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvOperationName"
        />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMultiplier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbChkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 separate horizontal linear layouts in your relative layout and you can adjust the weights and the heights as you like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/upLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOperationName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMultiplier"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbChkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOperationDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Textview below textview in horizontal linear layout

Not possible at all. Its clearly mentioned horizontal linear layout. So, you views are aligned horizontally only.

**Then**

If you set your linear layout `orientation` to `horizontal` your views are aligned horizontally & `orientation` to `vertical` your views are aligned vertically in linear manner that means one by one.

**Solution**
 One relative layout is enough for your requirements. Have a look at my answer [How relative layout views are aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494578/4824088) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOperationDesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Description" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOperationName"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Name" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMultiplier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbChkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if you want EditText and Checkbox in the same line as tvOperationName vertically just change orientation of secondLinearLayout to vertical and give gravity="center_horizontal" to secondLinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `LinearLayout` with orientation to `vertical`, and place both the `TextView`.

And remove `layout_below` property inside LinearLayout’s child view, as its useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOperationName"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOperationDesc"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvOperationName"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to have EditText and Checkbox in the same line as tvOperationName